# Best practices to update MongoDB document with multiple values using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What are the best practices to update a MongoDB document in which any property value can be changed?

I am thinking there are two methods to achieve this, I just don't know which one is best/most efficient or if there are others:

1. Send the entire object with the modified values and simply replace the old one on the back-end. Pretty straightforward, but it can get messy if you have any fields that get populated when the initial GET request is made.
2. Send an object with only the modified properties, compare the two on the back-end and replace old values with new ones. Here you also have to be careful with arrays so you don't overwrite the entire array.

I am using Mongoose, but this is more of a conceptual question, so I think it applies to any framework.

Comment: Depends on what you want, if you use PUT send the whole object, if you use PATCH send only the fields you want to modify. Never use GET to modify documents. There's nothing wrong in just sending the data you want to modify, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Small follow-up: can I just use POST? Are there any other reasons for using PUT, PATCH except being more explicit? I read up on the HTTP verbs, but found the explanations a bit confusing as all three are similar.

Comment: Yes using POST is ok too.